# Flexbox 2-column layout with overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to generate a 2-column-layout using flexbox with multiple rows. The right column should be small and pinned to the right side. The left column should fill the remaining space until the visible width is full and then not break the text, but hide it (using overflow).

Currently I'm using the following Code, that does not work:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-1 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    
}
.row {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-2 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-1">
        <span class="row">
        Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing yo mamma. Nullam sapien velizzle, its fo rizzle volutpizzle, suscipit for sure, brizzle vizzle, its fo rizzle. Pellentesque we gonna chung tortizzle. Sed eros. Stuff fizzle dolor dapibus turpizzle tempizzle shizznit. pellentesque nibh et turpizzle. Vestibulum izzle tortor. Gangsta mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa rhoncus fo shizzle. Izzle the bizzle habitasse bow wow wow dictumst. Dang dapibizzle. I'm in the shizzle we gonna chung urna, pretizzle eu, mattis mah nizzle, eleifend phat, nunc. Stuff suscipizzle. Integer sempizzle velit sizzle mofo.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-2">XX</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-1">
            <span class="row">
            Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing yo mamma. Nullam sapien velizzle, its fo rizzle volutpizzle, suscipit for sure, brizzle vizzle, its fo rizzle. Pellentesque we gonna chung tortizzle. Sed eros. Stuff fizzle dolor dapibus turpizzle tempizzle shizznit. pellentesque nibh et turpizzle. Vestibulum izzle tortor. Gangsta mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa rhoncus fo shizzle. Izzle the bizzle habitasse bow wow wow dictumst. Dang dapibizzle. I'm in the shizzle we gonna chung urna, pretizzle eu, mattis mah nizzle, eleifend phat, nunc. Stuff suscipizzle. Integer sempizzle velit sizzle mofo.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-2">XX</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `flex(0, 0, auto);` is not valid CSS BTW.

Comment: Does it have to be flex? This can be fixed without and give better browser support.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar: Thank you, corrected it.

Comment: It´s still not valid, should be `flex: 0 0 auto;`

Comment: Ok so now the problem is, that it is too long

Answer (score 0):

Relatively position `.flex-1` so you can absolutely position your span `.row`. Give it the size of your flexed `.flex-1` and apply the overflow you want.

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
}
.flex-1{
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.row{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-1">
    <span class="row">
      Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing yo mamma. Nullam sapien velizzle, its fo rizzle volutpizzle, suscipit for sure, brizzle vizzle, its fo rizzle. Pellentesque we gonna chung tortizzle. Sed eros. Stuff fizzle dolor dapibus turpizzle tempizzle shizznit. pellentesque nibh et turpizzle. Vestibulum izzle tortor. Gangsta mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa rhoncus fo shizzle. Izzle the bizzle habitasse bow wow wow dictumst. Dang dapibizzle. I'm in the shizzle we gonna chung urna, pretizzle eu, mattis mah nizzle, eleifend phat, nunc. Stuff suscipizzle. Integer sempizzle velit sizzle mofo.
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-2">XX</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-1">
    <span class="row">
      Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing yo mamma. Nullam sapien velizzle, its fo rizzle volutpizzle, suscipit for sure, brizzle vizzle, its fo rizzle. Pellentesque we gonna chung tortizzle. Sed eros. Stuff fizzle dolor dapibus turpizzle tempizzle shizznit. pellentesque nibh et turpizzle. Vestibulum izzle tortor. Gangsta mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa rhoncus fo shizzle. Izzle the bizzle habitasse bow wow wow dictumst. Dang dapibizzle. I'm in the shizzle we gonna chung urna, pretizzle eu, mattis mah nizzle, eleifend phat, nunc. Stuff suscipizzle. Integer sempizzle velit sizzle mofo.
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-2">XX</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my example was not minimal, please look at it again.

Comment: You want multiple rows but I'm not quite sure how you want them. Can you expain? I mean, with the code you have now you will get two identical rows.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;           /* Magic begins */
}
.flex-1 {
  flex: 1;                 /* Start at 0 width. Then grow to fill available space*/
  white-space: nowrap;     /* Prevent line breaks */
  overflow: hidden;        /* Hide overflow */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Show ellipsis */
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;           /* Magic begins */
}
.flex-1 {
  flex: 1;                 /* Start at 0 width. Then grow to fill available space */
  white-space: nowrap;     /* Prevent line breaks */
  overflow: hidden;        /* Hide overflow */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Show ellipsis */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.flex-2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-1">
    Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing yo mamma. Nullam sapien velizzle, its fo rizzle volutpizzle, suscipit for sure, brizzle vizzle, its fo rizzle. Pellentesque we gonna chung tortizzle. Sed eros. Stuff fizzle dolor dapibus turpizzle tempizzle shizznit. pellentesque nibh et turpizzle. Vestibulum izzle tortor. Gangsta mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa rhoncus fo shizzle. Izzle the bizzle habitasse bow wow wow dictumst. Dang dapibizzle. I'm in the shizzle we gonna chung urna, pretizzle eu, mattis mah nizzle, eleifend phat, nunc. Stuff suscipizzle. Integer sempizzle velit sizzle mofo.
  </div>
  <div class="flex-2">XX</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-1">
    Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing yo mamma. Nullam sapien velizzle, its fo rizzle volutpizzle, suscipit for sure, brizzle vizzle, its fo rizzle. Pellentesque we gonna chung tortizzle. Sed eros. Stuff fizzle dolor dapibus turpizzle tempizzle shizznit. pellentesque nibh et turpizzle. Vestibulum izzle tortor. Gangsta mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa rhoncus fo shizzle. Izzle the bizzle habitasse bow wow wow dictumst. Dang dapibizzle. I'm in the shizzle we gonna chung urna, pretizzle eu, mattis mah nizzle, eleifend phat, nunc. Stuff suscipizzle. Integer sempizzle velit sizzle mofo.
  </div>
  <div class="flex-2">XX</div>
</div>
```